# Need to use Isolates to speed up file processing in my app

Tags: flutter, dart

What the app does:

- Tapping on the FAB will:
- Create a single pdf with multiple pages or multiple png files. (the latter is selected as default, can be changed with a boolean in the parameter)
- The function will return a list of Files.

What is the problem:

- When there are more than 4 pages, the main isolate (app) will start to lag, and if more than 2 digits quantity the app will crash. I am trying to speed up the processing and hopefully prevent crashes.

What I have tried:

- Learning how to spawn an isolate but I still get a lot of errors here and there.
- Using an Isolate is very low-level programming and there are very few resources for it.

Some things may not make sense it's because this is a stripped-down version of a larger code. But everything should be working, in this example, it can either create pdf or png files, I prefer png files which is the one that consumes the most time.

For complete code https://github.com/fenchai23/pdf_isolate_test.git

[This](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/pdf/test/isolate_test.dart) is an example of Isolates from the author of the pdf package for isolates but it is very simple and not what I am trying to do.

This is the complete main.dart file:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Pdf Isolate Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _invoice = [
    {
      'qty': '1',
      'code': '27274-7J125 SET',
      'desc': 'A/A NIS PATHFINDER NEW 2015 - 2PC  ALMERA  27275-1N605',
      'invt': '615',
      'codealt': 'AC2503 SET',
      'descalt': '',
      'group': '10.FILTRO A/A',
      'price': '5.53',
      'disc1': '4.42',
      'globalPrice': '5.53',
      'total': '5.53'
    },
    {
      'qty': '1',
      'code': '27274-EA000 SET',
      'desc':
          'A/A NIS FRONTIER VQ40  YD25 PATHFIADER D40  VITARRA J20 27274-EL00A 27277-4JA0A',
      'invt': '1018',
      'codealt': 'AC2507SET',
      'descalt': '27277-4JA0A' 'GRAN VITARRA J20',
      'group': '10.FILTRO A/A',
      'price': '4.25',
      'disc1': '3.40',
      'globalPrice': '4.25',
      'total': '4.25'
    }
  ];

  static Future<List<File>> generateInvoice(Map args) async {
    print('creating pdf');

    final String _cartSubTotal = '1.00';
    final String _cartTotal = '1.01';
    final String _cartItbms = '7.00%';

    final DateTime _startTime = DateTime.now();

    final String dateTimeStamp = DateTime.now().toString();

    PdfImage _logo;

    List<Product> products = [];

    final List customRecordData = args['customRecordData'];
    final String customClientName = args['customClientName'];
    final String customClientDirection = args['customClientDirection'];
    final String customClientSeller = args['customClientSeller'];
    final bool isPdf = args['isPdf'];

    for (final k in customRecordData) {
      Product productsHolder = Product(
        k['qty'],
        k['code'],
        k['desc'],
        k['globalPrice'],
        k['total'],
      );
      products.add(productsHolder);
    }

    final pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();

    _logo = PdfImage.file(pdf.document,
        bytes: (await rootBundle.load('assets/icons/appIcon.png'))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List());

    pw.Widget _pdfHeader(pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Column(
        children: [
          pw.Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              pw.Expanded(
                child: pw.Column(
                  children: [
                    pw.Container(height: 2),
                    pw.Container(
                      decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: 2,
                          border:
                              pw.BoxBorder(color: PdfColors.blue, width: 2)),
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 10),
                      alignment: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
                      height: 60,
                      child: pw.DefaultTextStyle(
                        style: pw.TextStyle(
                          color: PdfColors.black,
                          fontSize: 10,
                        ),
                        child: pw.Column(
                          mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            pw.Text('Cliente:  $customClientName', maxLines: 1),
                            pw.Text('Dir:  $customClientDirection',
                                maxLines: 1),
                            pw.Text('Vend:  $customClientSeller', maxLines: 1),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pw.Expanded(
                child: pw.Column(
                  mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    pw.Container(
                      alignment: pw.Alignment.topRight,
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 30),
                      height: 72,
                      child: pw.Image(_logo),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if (context.pageNumber > 1) pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      );
    }

    pw.Widget _contentTable(pw.Context context) {
      const tableHeaders = ['CANT', 'CODIGO', 'DESCRIPCION', 'PRECIO', 'TOTAL'];

      return pw.Table.fromTextArray(
        context: context,
        border: null,
        cellAlignment: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
        headerDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: 2,
          color: PdfColors.blue,
        ),
        headerHeight: 25,
        cellHeight: 25,
        cellAlignments: {
          0: pw.Alignment.center,
          1: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
          2: pw.Alignment.centerLeft,
          3: pw.Alignment.center,
          4: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
        },
        headerStyle: pw.TextStyle(
          color: PdfColors.white,
          fontSize: 10,
          fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        cellStyle: const pw.TextStyle(
          color: PdfColors.black,
          fontSize: 10,
        ),
        rowDecoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
          border: pw.BoxBorder(
            bottom: true,
            color: PdfColors.grey,
            width: .5,
          ),
        ),
        headers: List<String>.generate(
          tableHeaders.length,
          (col) => tableHeaders[col],
        ),
        data: List<List<String>>.generate(
          products.length,
          (row) => List<String>.generate(
            tableHeaders.length,
            (col) => products[row].getIndex(col),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    pw.Widget _contentFooter(pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          pw.Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: pw.Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                pw.Text(
                  '',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                    color: PdfColors.black,
                    fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                pw.Container(
                  margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 8),
                  child: pw.Text(
                    '',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      color: PdfColors.black,
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                pw.Text(
                  '',
                  style: const pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 8,
                    lineSpacing: 5,
                    color: PdfColors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          pw.Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: pw.DefaultTextStyle(
              style: const pw.TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
                color: PdfColors.black,
              ),
              child: pw.Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  pw.Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      pw.Text('Sub Total:'),
                      pw.Text(_cartSubTotal),
                    ],
                  ),
                  pw.SizedBox(height: 5),
                  pw.Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      pw.Text('I.T.B.M.S:'),
                      pw.Text(_cartItbms),
                    ],
                  ),
                  pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.black),
                  pw.DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      color: PdfColors.black,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    child: pw.Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        pw.Text('Total:'),
                        pw.Text(_cartTotal),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    pw.Widget _pdfFooter(pw.Context context) {
      return pw.DefaultTextStyle(
        style: pw.Theme.of(context).defaultTextStyle.copyWith(
              color: PdfColors.grey,
            ),
        child: pw.Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            pw.Container(
              child: pw.Text(dateTimeStamp),
              margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
            ),
            pw.Container(
              alignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
              margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
              child: pw.Text(
                'Página ${context.pageNumber} de ${context.pagesCount}',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    // Here is where PDF (Invoice) is created

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        pageTheme: pw.PageTheme(
          buildBackground: (pw.Context context) => pw.FullPage(
            ignoreMargins: true,
            child: pw.Container(
              color: PdfColors.white,
            ),
          ),
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.letter.copyWith(
            marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
            marginTop: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
            marginLeft: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
            marginRight: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
          ),
        ),
        header: _pdfHeader,
        footer: _pdfFooter,
        build: (pw.Context context) => <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Padding(
            padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
          ),
          _contentTable(context),
          pw.Padding(
            padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
          ),
          _contentFooter(context),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    final timef = dateTimeStamp;
    // get a safe name for filenames
    final safeClientName =
        customClientName.replaceAll(RegExp("[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]"), '');
    final String fileName = '$timef--$customClientSeller--$safeClientName';

    File file;

    var imageList = List<File>();

    var pagesToPrint;

    pagesToPrint = await Printing.raster(pdf.save()).length;

    if (!isPdf) {
      int pageIndex = 1;

      await for (var page in Printing.raster(pdf.save(), dpi: 300)) {
        final image = await page.toPng();

        final String pageQty =
            (pagesToPrint > 1) ? '$pageIndex-$pagesToPrint' : '1-1';

        file = File("${output.path}/$fileName--$pageQty.png");

        await file.writeAsBytes(image);

        imageList.add(file);

        pageIndex++;
      }
    } else {
      file = File("${output.path}/$fileName.pdf");

      await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());

      imageList.add(file);
    }

    print('done creating pdf');

    final int elapsedTime = DateTime.now().difference(_startTime).inSeconds;

    print('time elapsed: $elapsedTime seconds');

    return imageList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final tempInvoice = [];
    for (final Map k in _invoice) {
      print(k);
      tempInvoice.add(k);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      _invoice.addAll(tempInvoice);
    }

    print(_invoice);
    print(_invoice.length);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text('If animation lags then we know isolate failed.')
        ],
      ))),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await getTemporaryDirectory()
            ..delete(recursive: true);

          var result = await compute(generateInvoice, {
            'customRecordData': _invoice,
            'customClientName': 'Obama',
            'customClientDirection': 'USA',
            'customClientSeller': '1',
            'isPdf': false,
          });

          print(result);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Product {
  const Product(
    this.qty,
    this.code,
    this.desc,
    this.price,
    this.total,
  );

  final String qty;
  final String code;
  final String desc;
  final String price;
  final String total;

  String getIndex(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return qty;
      case 1:
        return truncateWithEllipsis(25, code.trim());
      case 2:
        return truncateWithEllipsis(50, desc.trim());
      case 3:
        return price;
      case 4:
        return total;
    }
    return '';
  }
}

String truncateWithEllipsis(int cutoff, String myString) {
  return (myString.length <= cutoff)
      ? myString
      : '${myString.substring(0, cutoff)}...';
}
```

While the app runs fine, when I try to run the compute code it gives me this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
```

I have tried giving main() `async` and also     `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`
but it continues to call the same error.

btw this is the part that takes the most time.

```
if (!isPdf) {
  int pageIndex = 1;

  await for (var page in Printing.raster(pdf.save(), dpi: 300)) {
    final image = await page.toPng();

    final String pageQty =
        (pagesToPrint > 1) ? '$pageIndex-$pagesToPrint' : '1-1';

    file = File("${output.path}/$fileName--$pageQty.png");

    await file.writeAsBytes(image);

    imageList.add(file);

    pageIndex++;
  }
} else {
  file = File("${output.path}/$fileName.pdf");

  await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());

  imageList.add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I haven't seen it but where do you spawn your Isolate?

I could be a little bit tricky to generate your on Isolate, but Flutter have a great workaround and it's called the **compute** function. Give it a try! [Compute Flutter API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html)

Or try this page it helped me to get a good view over this function. [Compute with Flutter](https://dev.to/fallenstedt/compute-with-flutter-3p6o)

Maybe good to know is that Dart  is a single threaded language, that means you can run your code in background on a second thread and in the main thread you can show a loading indicator. Workaround is to generate more threads or to vectorize your code.[Dart vectorize](https://dartdoc.takyam.com/articles/simd/)

Tom

Comment: yes there was no compute function in my code. But I have researched more about computes and it seems it needs a static function, can only pass 1 parameter. Everything done. But it gives me this error when I try to run it. Unhandled Exception: Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.

Comment: That's right, you can only pass one argument. But one argument could be more than one thing! List, Map,....; It doesn't has to be a static function, it can also be a global! Before you call the compute function you have to call: widget.WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  in an extra method before the compute function is called

Comment: Give it a look: https://www.gladimdim.org/flutter-unblocking-ui-thread-with-isolates-compute-function-ck03qrwnj000peks1zvhvko1x

Comment: WoW great article! I swear I googled crazy yesterday all day, I felt burnt out and a headache from it. How did you find it? by the way I did call widget.WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); in the main() method before the runApp method. It still did not work (gave me the same error). I have googled many times and people seem to use .then but It seems this method is not a future, so maybe they have updated the method. I will continue to read the article and see if I can find any tricks

Comment: I have updated the post where you can find the code that takes the most time. I do mot know how to compute it.

Comment: take that code and put it into a new method, in a new file. So that it's a global function. Then you go back into the previous file and call the new function with the compute function.

Comment: I just realized isolates will not help, because the pdf package needs to get all the pdf pages into the memory, this gets worse when there is a need to convert them into png too. Which is why the device runs oom. The owner of the package said that in order to instead of writing them into memory, write into a file will need a complete rework of how the package works. I gave up on this already.

Comment: You really shouldn't use "Look at this link" format on StqckOverflow, with any code examples or explanations. Only a year has passed, and this link is already unavailable.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense - but you can use google to search for the string ;)           
flutter-unblocking-ui-thread-with-isolates-compute-function